# print pdf directly to printer windows

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I have a windows app that prints pdfs directly to a printer.  Everything is working but for some reason for each pdf to print I see the pdf reader Nitro Pro pop up in the background then close.

Is there a way to keep the window from poping up.  It does not seem to effect the over application but just kind of annoying.

```
private void PrintDocument(string printer, string fileName)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Arguments = "\"" + printer + "\"",
            Verb = "PrintTo",
            FileName = fileName,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,         
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

        Process p = new Process { StartInfo = info };
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit(5000);
        if (p.HasExited == false)
        {
            p.Kill();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

Windows can't print a file directly, it relies on a program to do so. It will use whatever application has configured itself to handle the `PrintTo` verb for the particular file extension. In your case it appears the application is Nitro Pro.

It's possible that you can find and install an application that can print the file without opening a window to do so, but that's beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: +1 - For the OP, see the last command on this page for printing directly by invoking Nitro Pro which is a process that you should be able to hide if it bugs you enough. http://support.nitropdf.com/entries/21563477-Using-Nitro-via-the-command-line